# Resteasy Jackson POST

Tags: jax-ws, jackson, resteasy

I am trying to do a POST on a webservice using RESTEasy and Jackson for JSON bindings.

My client interface looks like

```
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface MyClientProxy {

    @POST
    @Path("/messages/send")
    ClientResponse<FooResponse> send(@QueryParam("foo") Foo foo);    
}
```

And object Foo is something like:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Foo implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty
    String bar;

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

But now when I run the test, I can see from the server that I get a POST looking like:

```
{
    "foo": "com.x.y.Foo@1d75249c"
}
```

How come the object Foo is not being properly serialized to JSON?

Comment: It looks like someone invoke 'toString' method on the object and after that serialize it to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a default constructor `public Foo() {}` :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Foo implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty
    String bar;

    public Foo() {}

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```